# Flutter: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable (Android studio update "Electric Eel" problem)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, java-home

Today I was going on with my flutter project, then the Android studio show me a new update, I clicked on "update".

Once it completed and installed the update, this message start appearing to me:

> The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe`

I have tried so many solutions, and made sure that I have the latest JDK version `19`, and the environment variables didn't change, but still not working and showing this message to me!!!

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: folder structure]

check new installed android studio has the jre folder empty or not . if  u find any folder rather than jre ex: jbr then move all files from jbr to jre

Comment: I did it, but android studio never worked again!!
It's horrible solution

Comment: ok then set JAVA_HOME and see if  android studio works or not

Comment: Actually this solution worked with me but not with moving files "cut" , it worked by copy files from jbr to jre.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried it but still not working. Why?

Comment: you can do clean install and rename jbr to jre if u want to do flutter developemt with vscode