# Previous Flutter apps are not working with latest android studio version Electric Eel

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I tried every solution I can think about, but it still not working.

I'm getting this error while running my app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: do invalidate cache and restart. May be it will resolve .

Answer (score 0):

1. add java to system environment variable.
2. restart your IDE

if it doesn't work

3. try to run after restarting your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Go To the android studio directory (Default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio) remove the JRE folder run cmd as administrator

cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio mklink /D "jre" "jbr" - [REF](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674#issuecomment-1381685888).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, you have to do as what income in these posts:

1- [JAVA_HOME & JAVA path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75121746/flutter-the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid-i-cannot-find-the-java-execu)

2- [This to return every thing to the normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917977/execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesigningdebug-java-util-concurrent-exec)

after that every thing will be ok, I've done all of that since a while today.